# run unsafe app in a sandbox on regular user account

Tags: permission, user-account

I want to use Visual Studio Code with a lot of extensions. Extensions in VS Code are not verified and can be dangerous. I want to run VS Code + extensions in a secure way **AND** without the need to log out from my main account.

How to do it? I thought about this:

1. Create account `unsecure-apps`
2. Install there VS Code with extensions
3. Add read-write access to all files in `/Users/myMainAccount/sharedFolder` to account `unsecure-apps`
4. Run VS Code from `myMainAccount` by `sudo -u unsecure-apps vscode`

Will it be secure? Could there be a simpler way?

Comment: I suspect the only way is to create a virtual machine to run VSCode in

Comment: Just creating a user  unsecure-apps and logging in from the login screen is probably easier to use and just as secure as you suggest. macOS has quick user switching.